# How to show keypad on click of a span element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By default mobile devices show its keypad on click of input field. But I want to open keypad on click of a span element not input. How to do that in javascript?

Note: I can't bind span element with input field using 'for' because I can't add input field at all.

Comment: No, you can't. The keyboard appears for elements requiring keyboard input.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I understand what you're saying I was just asking if there is any hack we can use to open keypad (using JS). Actually I'm building a terminal where I am trying to simulate input using span tag.

Comment: Here is the link of demo app where I require this functionality. Note: keypad is not showing when you open this demo in mobile. (https://codepen.io/abhishekraj/pen/MrMdYZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Javascript, you can do it in HTML

```
<span contenteditable="true">Click me and I'll pop up a keyboard</span>
```